# JSON data and getting/changing a property in it using a variable

Tags: javascript, json, api

To begin, I am not sure if this question will make much sense. I will do my best to explain.

I am working on a project looking at U.S. Census bureau information. The part of the object that I am looking at looks like this: (Please note that this is only part of the object.)

```
Object {MTFCC: "G5020", OID: 207903717468543, GEOID: "13135050431", STATE:     
"13", COUNTY: "135"…}
AREALAND: 5416158
AREAWATER: 34463
B19013_001E: "45543"
```

The part that I am interested in is: B19013_001E which happens to be the code for Median Household Income. In order to get specifically the Median household income I would do:

```
response.features[1].properties.B19013_001E
```

Everything works find up to this point. However, my problem is the following: I want to change that code to have other values. So, if the individual wants to look for median_male_age, whose code is B01002_002E I do not want to hard code in B01002_002E as the following:

```
response.features[1].properties.B01002_002E
```

The above line would work. But again I want something that can be determined by a variable so that I will not have to hard code in the special code. So, I want a code that is like this: (just an example!)

```
var value = prompt("What do you want to look at: ")
//In this case value would be the special code like B01002_002E which the user enters.
console.log(response.features[1].properties.value)
```

Whenever I do this, I get no information back. At first I thought I had the wrong type but I do not believe that is the issue. (I tried converting to a number and back to a string etc.) Any help on this will be great!

Comment: Close! `console.log(response.features[1].properties[value])`

Comment: Use `response.features[1].properties[propertyVar]`

Comment: Oh wow! I was really close! That seems to have worked! Thank you! I cannot believe it was that simple!

Comment: @MikeCuddy Glad it helped. :) Don't forget to accept an answer to close out your question so others will know it was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

First, MDN has a great doc on [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). It is worth the read.

Second, for your own edification, **JSON** is a string and not an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a **POJO** or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different. :)

Third, for your question in particular, you want to use bracket notation when [accessing an object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) via a variable. So in this case it would be:

```
console.log(response.features[1].properties[value])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the information as well I do appreciate it! Have a great day/weekend!